# Is the reciprocal of a vector defined in a way to allow the reverse of scalar or dot products?

Tags: vectors

To simply present the question I will be using the two vectors (velocity and displacment), and the scalar time. As you may know, $$\vec{s} = \vec{v}\cdot t $$ This makes perfect sense as multiplying a vector by a scalar gives a vector with a different magnitude. But my question is when we want to calculate the time taken given that we know the velocity at which an object was travling and the total displacment it was displaced, we will have to equate the following equation $$\vec{s}/\vec{v}$$ But what does that mean? we have two operations on vectors regarding multiplication (i.e the dot product and the scalar product), but $$\vec{s}/\vec{v}$$ doesnt fit in any of the two. The first intuitive thing that came to mind is to think of it like a vector product of two vectors assuming that $$\frac{1}{\vec{v}}$$ is a vector. But here I face two problems, 1. I dont know if $$\frac{1}{\vec{v}}$$ (v being a velocity vector) gives a vector or, in other words if a recprocal of a vector gives another vector. I tried to google this but I couldnt get an answer that I can understand. I only have a high school level of mathematics so please try consider that when you answer the question if possible. The second thing is when I learn this at school I have not applied the vector product to find the answer I would just manipulate the numbers as they are just scalars. But what is the right way?

So to just put my question in short words **Does the recprocal of a vector give a vector? And can a product of a vector (a) and the recporcal of another vector(b) treated as a vector product (is a/b = scalar product) or is there another way to calcaulate that?**

Comment: My question might be wordy so if you undestand what I am asking I would realy apprciate your help in simplfying it!

Comment: Assuming the velocity is not zero, then dotting each side of the first equation with $\vec{v}\,$ creates a scalar equation which can be solved. 
$$
\vec{v}\cdot\vec{s} = \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}\;t
\quad\implies\quad
t = \frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{s}}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}
$$

Comment: @greg Can you check if the answer I posted is exactly what you told me, I just wanted to check if I have understood what you said. if it is correct, I will have a follow up question. Thank you so much BTW sir.

Comment: @greg Just a quick question is $$\frac{\vec{v}}{\vec{v}} = 1$$ or not a posssible operation. I think it isnt a possible.

Comment: It's possible, it's just not very common.  It's called Hadamard (aka element-wise) multiplication $(s\odot v)$ and division $(s\oslash v)$.

Comment: @greg thank you sir that was very helpful. can you refer me to a book or a site so that I can get more read on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@greg gave me the kind of answer I needed. I am posting this so that other people can find it in the future.

so $\vec{s} = \vec{v}t$ is a valid equation as already mentioned. If you want to calculate time from this given, it isnt easy to just divide the displacment vector by the velocity vector, but instead you will have to convert both of the vectors into a scalar, and you can do that using dot (scalar) product. The step is as follows,

If you multiply both sides by the veclocity vector, the equation should still be the same as perfoming similar opertations in both sides of an equation doesn't change the equlity. so $$\vec{s} = \vec{v}\cdot t$$
$$\implies \vec{v}\cdot\vec{s} = \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}\;t$$
From dot products we know $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} = v^2$,where v is the magnitude of the velocity vector.

$$\implies t = \frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{s}}{v^2}$$
Now the problem has been completely simplified to just scalars as the result of $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{s}$ is a scalar which can be written as $v\cdot\hat{v}\cdot\vec{s}$, where $\hat{v}$ is the unit vector in the direction of the velocity vector.
$$\implies t = \frac{v\cdot\hat{v}\cdot\vec{s}}{v^2}$$
$$\implies t = \frac{\hat{v}\cdot\vec{s}}{v}$$

Moreover, as suggested by @Devansh_Singh, incase where the velocity and the displacment vector are in the same direction the equation can simplify to just $t = \frac{s}{v}$ where $s$ is the magnitude of the displacment vector.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics vector space is an additive abelian(commutative) group and satisfies vector distribution over scalar addition, scalar distribution over vector addition and other two properties.

Scalar is a field(a ring). When we talk about velocity in physics then as we can see it satisfies all the properties of vector space so it is a vector. But, a vector does not guarantee that it has an inverse like field( see all the properties of vector space it does not say that if field of dimension n contains one more property apart from vector properties, it cannot be a vector space) as you are saying.

I recommend taking vectors as scalars or most simple would be breaking vector into individual dimensions(components) and then in individual dimension you are free to take each component of the vector as scalar.
Try this.

Comment: thank you sir, that helped. Can you check what I posted to see if I have understood you correctly. I combined your answer and another comment to come up with a short note